# On 1x2 convolution and combining gradients

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So I'm trying to understand convolution and the process on making gradients and I wanted to just see the horizontal gradient of the 1x2 operator on an image named I1. When I tried to use this code I only get a black screen so I'm trying to figure out what went wrong here,sans using conv of course. (I'm also going to try out Sobel too, so I'd like some tips on how to get that going.)

```
    I1    = uint8(round(sum(C1,3)/3));

figure,imshow(I1);

Kern =[-1,1];
Omega = zeros([size(I1,1) size(I1,2)]);

for i=1:ROWS
    for j=1:COLS
        Work = double(I1(i,j)).*Kern;
        Omega(i,j) = sum(Work(:));  
    end
end

figure,imshow(uint8(Omega));
```

Comment: You should probably use `I1` somewhere in your loop. You are currently computing using only zeros.

Comment: You declared `Endpoint` probably to use as the output, then forgot, and user `Omega` as output, and too forgot to use an input, so you chose `Endpoint` as the initial image. `Endpoint` is all zeros, so its convolution results, unsurprisingly, in zeros.

Comment: I edited the stuff around, I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: What type is `C1`? If it's a double, then you're rounding its value to `0` or `1`, which would cause the resulting image to appear black. You're also multiplying the kernel by a single pixel, which is not what you want, I think.

Comment: C1 is the input image that I'm turning into an intensity image I1. So should I remove the period then?

Comment: Tried sans the period and nothing.

Comment: @MarorinQ That doesn't answer my question. I see that `C1` is an image, but what is the class of `C1` is it double, or uint8, or something else? As for removing the period, no that's not correct either. You need 2 pixels from `I1` to multiply with the 2-element kernel. But that's not going to do anything if your original `I1` only has values of `0` and `1`, so fix that first. p.s. If you tag me like @beaker, I'll be notified when you respond to me. Otherwise I won't know unless I check back here.

Comment: @beaker It's a uint8. C1 is the image directly received by imread. I'm a bit confused on how to pick out the two pixels when you say you need2 pixels from I1.

Comment: Can you post the original image `C1` so we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: @beaker Here's the image that's I'm working on. https://imgur.com/a/T2cGh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're only using 1 pixel from `I1` to multiply by your kernel. Since you're using one value, the end effect is:

```
a.*[-1 1]
```

which gives you

```
[-a a]
```

When you sum this, obviously you get zero. To fix this, you'll need to use the same number of pixels from `I1` as you have elements in your kernel (in this case, 2). This will also mean that you need to adjust your loop indices:

```
for i=1:ROWS-1       % avoid accessing outside image
    for j=1:COLS-1
        Work = double(I1(i,j:j+1)).*Kern;   % j:j+1 gives us 2 pixels
        Omega(i,j) = sum(Work(:));  
    end
end
```

You can also condense the two lines inside the loop into one:

```
Kern = [-1;1];   % make Kern a column vector
...

for i=1:ROWS-1
    for j=1:COLS-1
        Omega(i,j) = double(I1(i,j:j+1))*Kern;  % vector multiplication, not elementwise
    end
end
```

Another thing you might want to try is use `imagesc(Omega)` instead of `imshow`. `imagesc` will scale the values of the image so it's more visible.

Comment: Ahh I see! So I'm curious with this, in making the horizontal and then the vertical gradients, how would one combine the two pictures then? I'm also interested in using the Sobel operator so I'm wondering what sort of changes one would have to do for flipping the kernel.

Comment: There are numerous questions/answers on building your own image convolution on Stack Overflow, just search around. Since the Sobel operator is separable, you can compute the vertical and horizontal components individually and then combine them. In this case you will probably want to ignore the "condensed" version I gave because it will probably only be confusing. You will also probably need to use 3 pixels from the image at a time since the Sobel operator is usually given as `[1;2;1]; [1,0,-1]`.

Comment: Right, I was just going to use the vertical gradient, then make a kernel of the horizontal, and then do it like that. I'm just stuck on combining the two gradients together, if you'd know how to do that. would using cat(2,vert,horizontal) work for that?

Comment: Usually, it's `sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2)`, but sometimes `Gx/2+Gy/2` is used for more speed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Comment: Hmm so I tried making a secondary kernel to do the horizontal gradient, and it doesn't seem to be showing a difference for that. Kernh= Kern'; Omegah = zeros([size(I1,1) size(I1,2)]); for i=1:ROWS-1 for j=1:COLS-1 Workh = double(I1(i,j:j+1)).*Kernh; Omegah(i,j) = sum(Workh(:)); end end

Comment: @MarorinQ That would be a different question, where you can format your code and give enough details about what's going wrong.